# Getting Corrupted PDF file error in local storage

Tags: javascript, laravel, base64

I'm getting PDF file base64 string in controller. When i save it to local storage it shows an error of corrupted PDF (not decoded). How i can solve this issue?
Can someone figure out?

base64 String:

```
"data:application/pdf;filename=generated.pdf;base64,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"
```

```
 $pdf = $request->get('pdf_file');
 $id = $request->get('user_id');
 $data = explode( ',', $pdf);
 $file_name = time() . '-test.pdf';
 $path = public_path() . '/images/users/' . $file_name;

 file_put_contents($path, $data[1]);
```

Comment: You cannot use ` file_put_contents($path, $data[1]);` for insertinga  data to the PDF\

Comment: I'm just using this for saving in local storage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this updates solution this should definitely work for you.

```
$pdf = $request->get('pdf_file');
$id = $request->get('user_id');

$data = explode( ',', $pdf);

# Decode the Base64 string, making sure that it contains only valid characters
$bin = base64_decode($data[1], true);    


$file_name = time() . '-test.pdf';
$path = public_path() . '/images/users/' . $file_name;


# Write the PDF contents to a local file
file_put_contents($path, $bin);
```

Comment: Exception: Missing the PDF file signature

Comment: So that means file coming into your request is not valid .PDF extension file, Please try again by providing valid PDF file.

Comment: I added string in question.

Comment: Please check my answer again and try now I have updated few things.

Comment: I'm getting of error Request URI too long on server.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $pdf = $request->get('pdf_file');
 $id = $request->get('user_id');

 $array_1 = explode(";", $pdf);
 $array_2 = explode(",", array_1[1]);
 $data = base64_decode($array_2[1]);

 $file_name = time() . '-test.pdf';
 $path = public_path() . '/images/users/' . $file_name;

 file_put_contents($path, $data);
```

Try this piece of code. It is hard to explain base64 format exploding by writing, so if you just `dd();` it will be very clear to you.

Comment: Still the saved file is corrupted